# SwiftUI: Dynamically adding views with ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

I want to dynamically switch between sub-views using an ObservableObject. Note in the following code that the line `AnotherView().environmentObject(currentState)` works, but the line `dynamicallyAddedSecondView` fails with `No ObservableObject of type CurrentState found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for CurrentState may be missing as an ancestor of this view.` Is there a way for the dynamically added view to be considered as an ancestor of the ContentView environment?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ObservedObjectTestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class CurrentState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stateName = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var currentState = CurrentState()

    var dynamicallyAddedSecondView = AnotherView()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AnotherView().environmentObject(currentState)
            dynamicallyAddedSecondView
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var currentState: CurrentState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current state: \(currentState.stateName)")
            Button("Change state", action: {currentState.stateName = "new state"})
      }
    .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: try moving `.environmentObject(currentState)` to the `VStack`, like: `VStack{...}.environmentObject(currentState)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing EnvironmentObject for dynamicallyAddedSecondView, i have added it below

```
struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var currentState = CurrentState()

var dynamicallyAddedSecondView = AnotherView()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        AnotherView().environmentObject(currentState)
        dynamicallyAddedSecondView.environmentObject(currentState) //HERE
    }
    .padding()
}
}
```

Also if you need CurrentState object across all of your views then you can pass EnvironmentObject from root, in this way you don't need to pass object from one view to another every time

```
@main
struct ObservedObjectTestApp: App {

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(CurrentState()) //HERE
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't init objects in body like that. Best way to fix it is to make a singleton.

Comment: you already have `@StateObject var currentState = CurrentState()` in `ContentView`,
doing `ContentView().environmentObject(CurrentState())` in the `App` is wrong.

Comment: Please read the description i've added in the answer

Comment: 'Also if you need CurrentState object across all of your views then you can pass EnvironmentObject from root, in this way you don't need to pass object from one view to another every time". Ok, but how does AnotherView() refer to the state object? ContentView.environmentObject(CurrentState()) doesn't put the state object in AnotherView's scope, I'm guessing because AnotherView is instantiated but not declared within ContentView.

Comment: Actually that was just a small tip if you want to access some object on entire app, but if you really need to use @StateObject then obviously you shouldn't use that way, my answer is based on two sections, first one was the solution of your question and second one was a tip that is not relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

use this simple approach to pass your `currentState` to all "sub" Views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var currentState = CurrentState()
    var dynamicallyAddedSecondView = AnotherView()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AnotherView()
            dynamicallyAddedSecondView
        }.environmentObject(currentState)   // <-- here
        .padding()
    }
}
```